# Assign text color based on background-color

Tags: css, sass, frontend

I need to apply a red color for the paragraph text, if the background of the paragraph is white or transparent and yellow otherwise (the color of the background is not white), using just CSS or SASS preprocessor

Something like that :

```
p {
  @if $selectedP.background == white || transparent {
    color: red;
  } @else {
    color: yellow;
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **`@mixin`** to change text color based on the background.

```html
<p class="white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit quaerat, non rem enim commodi harum, explicabo atque reiciendis esse nemo veritatis quisquam, deserunt at et. Aspernatur maxime inventore ut laboriosam necessitatibus dicta eius fuga! Deserunt facere totam voluptatibus. Praesentium, velit! A nobis molestias maiores iste dicta qui ut, hic repudiandae.</p>
<p class="blue">Cupiditate, quam praesentium, delectus consequatur quae eos doloribus officiis aut, dignissimos porro numquam ea expedita odio quis adipisci saepe excepturi quibusdam temporibus et amet dolorem! Nisi accusantium earum quo vero reprehenderit error debitis totam natus incidunt, consequuntur harum aut at magnam! Reiciendis fugiat excepturi magnam dolorum sint quo atque sunt?</p>
```

```css
@mixin colors($bg-white: true) {
  @if $bg-white {
    color: red;
  } @else {
    color: yellow;
  }
}

.white {
  @include colors($bg-white: true);
  background-color: white;
}

.blue {
  @include colors($bg-white: false);
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, the problem is that I do not know when calling the `@include colors(...)` if the background is white or not. I need to send it when selecting the elements something like that : `@includes colors(selectedElement.bgColor)`. Also I can not add class attribute to elements in the HTML

Comment: @YassinMohamadi What you exactly want to do is not possible with CSS. You will need to implement JavaScript in your project.